How do I make a microservice not return 408?
I am trying to make a main API talk to a login server to get the API keys. The login server (based on Express) answers requests that I make, although based on the client's requirements (AKA my teacher), they want to be able to log in from the main API, so when they do a request to /login, I proxy it to the login server. But seemingly the login server doesn't respond to those requests, so it doesn't really work and returns a 408 timed out.
I have already tried multiple proxy methods, both http-proxy-middleware and doing it manually with the nodejs built in http client. I have theorized using Curl as well but decided that's a bad idea because of bash injection
I cannot use nginx like Marc said, I have to use Express for both the login server and the main api server. The main API server works mostly as expected (it's not fully done yet)
Here is the code I have when I try to forward the request manually
const express = require("express")
const http = require("http")
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
require("dotenv").config()
app.use("/login", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log("Redirecting to login server")
    req.headers["host"] = "localhost:" + process.env.LOGIN_PORT
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.headers))
    const proxyreq = http.request({
        hostname: 'localhost',
        port: process.env.LOGIN_PORT,
        method: "POST",
        headers: req.headers,
        path: "/"
    }, (response) => {
        console.log("Response from login server: " + response.statusCode)
        if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
            res.status(response.statusCode).send()
            return
        }
        const cookies = response.headers['set-cookie'];

        if (cookies) {
            cookies.forEach(cookie => {
                const token = cookie.split(';')[0].split('=')[1];
                res.cookie("token", token, { httpOnly: true });
            });
        }
        res.send()
    })
    proxyreq.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error('Error with the request:', err.message);
    });

    proxyreq.write(JSON.stringify(req.body))
    proxyreq.end()
    console.log(proxyreq.outputData[0].data)

})
app.listen(process.env.PORT)

And here is the HTTP request the last console.log logs
POST / HTTP/1.1
host: localhost:3001
user-agent: curl/7.81.0
accept: */*
content-type: application/json
content-length: 42
Connection: keep-alive

{"username":"admin","password":"hallo"}

The command I use to do the request is
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"username": 
"admin", "password": "hallo"}' http://localhost:3000/login -v

(I know, my username and password are very insecure, but I can do that in non-prod enviroments)

You need to add more details. What kind of "login server"? Why not use nginx? Does the other stuff work as expected? What kind of tools you can/should use? Add a lot of more details! (And at least some code)

Thanks @Marc, I added the code I use, the HTTP request it generates and some more details

You code the login & api server both your self? Can you add a How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Yes, I have to code them both myself according to my teacher

Im divided/have mixed feelings if i should post a answer for a homework: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/5781499

Thats fair, but so you know, my school allows for this, with the idea that when you are at work you can generally do this too

Thats not a matter if you school allows this or not. Its a matter of the platform/rules we are using here. Let me give you 2 very strong hints: Drop that header/cookie stuff and pipe the request/response streams. 2) Adjust the "path" (pathname) & method parameter what your auth api expects.
